# python re.search not working on multiline string

Tags: python, regex, multiline

I have this file loaded in string:

```
// some preceding stuff
static char header_data[] = {
    1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,
    1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,
    1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,
    1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,
    0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,
    1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,
    0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,
    0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,
    0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,
    0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,
    1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,
    1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,
    1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,
    1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,
    1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,
    1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1
    };
```

I want to get only the block with ones and zeros, and then somehow process it.

I imported re, and tried:

```
In [11]: re.search('static char header_data(.*);', src, flags=re.M)

In [12]: re.findall('static char header_data(.*);', src, flags=re.M)
Out[12]: []
```

Why doesn't it match anything? How to fix this? (It's python3)

Comment: Think about the non-greedy match in my answer. Otherwise you will match more than one parethis section. But it depends how your source file will look like.

Comment: @wenzul Actually it's the last brace in the file, but I'll add that, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: @wenzul I rejected your edit, because it's not improving it at all. When I encountered the problem, I googled almost exactly what I now have in the title - this way people will easily find it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use the `re.S` flag, not  `re.M`.

- `re.M` (`re.MULTILINE`) controls the behavior of `^` and `$` (whether they match at the start/end of the entire string or of each line).
- `re.S` (`re.DOTALL`) controls the behavior of the `.` and is the option you need when you want to allow the dot to match newlines.

See also the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE).

Comment: Thanks, works great now. The "MULTILINE" name is a bit confusing

Answer (score 3):

> and then somehow process it.

Here we go to get a useable list out of the file:

```
import re
match = re.search(r"static char header_data\[\] = {(.*?)};", src, re.DOTALL)
if match:
    header_data = "".join(match.group(1).split()).split(',')
    print header_data
```

`.*?` is a non-greedy match so you really will get just the value between this set of braces.

A more expicit way without `DOTALL` or `MULTILINE` would be

```
match = re.search(r"static char header_data\[\] = {([01,\s\r\n]*?)};", src)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the format of the file does not change, you might as well not resort to `re` but use slices. Something on these lines could be useful

```
>>> file_in_string
'\n// some preceding stuff\nstatic char header_data[] = {\n    1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0
,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,\n    1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,\n    1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1
,0,1,0,1,1,\n    1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,\n    0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
,0,1,1,\n    1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,\n    0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0
,0,\n    0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,\n    0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,\
n    0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,\n    1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,\n
 1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,\n    1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,\n    1,1
,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,\n    1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,\n    1,1,1,1
,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1\n    };\n'
>>> lines = file_in_string.split()
>>> lines[9:-1]
['1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,', '1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,', '1,1,0,
1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,', '1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,', '0,0,0,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,', '1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,', '0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,
1,0,0,0,0,', '0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,', '0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,
0,', '0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,', '1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,', '1,
1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,', '1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,', '1,1,0,1,0,
1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,', '1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,', '1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,
0,1,1,1,1,1,1']
```