# Multi-line regex fails to match even though individual items to

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to search through a bunch of large text files for specific information.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# pythnon 3.4
import re
sometext = """
    lots
    of
    text here
    Sentinel starts
    --------------------
    item_one               item_one_result
    item_two               item_two_result
    --------------------
    lots
    more
    text here
    Sentinel starts
    --------------------
    item_three               item_three_result
    item_four                item_four_result
    item_five                item_five_result
    --------------------
    even
    more
    text here
    Sentinel starts
    --------------------
    item_six                item_six_result
    --------------------
    """
sometextpattern = re.compile( '''.*Sentinel\s+starts.*$                           # sentinel
                                 ^.*-+.*$                                         # dividing line
                                 ^.*\s+(?P<itemname>\w+)\s+(?P<itemvalue>\w+)\s+  # item details
                                 ^.*-+.*$                                         # dividing line                                  
                              ''', flags = re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)
print( re.findall( sometextpattern, sometext ) )
```

Individually, the sentinels and dividing lines match on their own.  How do I make this work together?  i.e. I would like this to print:

```
[('item_one','item_one_result'),('item_two','item_two_result'),('item_three','item_three_result'),('item_four','item_four_result'),('item_five','item_five_results'),('item_six','item_six_results')]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [python re.search not working on multiline string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250171/python-re-search-not-working-on-multiline-string)

Comment: Doesn't look like a duplicate question to me since the REs are so much different and the flags advice for that question is exactly the opposite of the advice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these regex:

```
for m in re.findall(r'(?:Sentinel starts\n[-\n]*)([^-]+)', sometext, flags=re.M ):
    print(list(re.findall(r'(\w+)\s+(\w+)', m)))
```

It gives you a list of key,value tuples:

```
# [('item_one', 'item_one_result'), ('item_two', 'item_two_result')]
# [('item_three', 'item_three_result'), ('item_four', 'item_four_result')]
```

Because the text has trailing spaces, change the regex in the for statement for this one:

```
r'(?:Sentinel starts\s+-*)([^-]*\b)'
```

Comment: Looks amazing, but notice the leading indentation in the original question.

Comment: To account for the indentation, change the regex in the for statement for the one added at the end of the answer.

Comment: This is very close to what I finally used.  This approach has the nice feature of dividing the corpus into sections and then separately finding the items I need in each section.

Answer (score 1):

The regex multiline matching tag only makes `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of each line, respectively. If you want to match multiple lines, you will need to add a whitespace meta character `'\\s'` to match the newline.

```
.*Sentinel\s+starts.*$\s
^.*-+.*$\s
^.*\s+(?P<itemname>\w+)\s+(?P<itemvalue>\w+)\s+
^.*-+.*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ip-ZNYe6Rr2hPMFv)

---

Also the string you are using does not have the required string escaping. I would recommend using the `r''` type string instead. That way you do not have to escape your backslashes.

Comment: Since I was in the middle of writing up the same thing with a Debuggex demo, I've added it to your answer. If you think it gets in the way, feel free to revert it, move it, etc.

Comment: This does not match item_one nor item_three.  Haven't yet figured out how to fix that.  BTW, debuggex seems very cool.

Answer (score 1):

Use four capturing groups in-order to print the text you want inside the list.

```
>>> import regex
>>> text = """    lots
    of
    text here
    Sentinel starts
    --------------------
    item_one               item_one_result
    item_two               item_two_result
    --------------------
    lots
    more
    text here
    Sentinel starts
    --------------------
    item_three               item_three_result
    item_four                item_four_result
    item_five                item_five_result
    --------------------
    even
    more
    text here
    Sentinel starts
    --------------------
    item_six                item_six_result
    --------------------"""
>>> regex.findall(r'(?:(?:\bSentinel starts\s*\n\s*-+\n\s*|-+)|(?<!^)\G) *(\w+) *(\w+)\n*', text)
[('item_one', 'item_one_result'), ('item_two', 'item_two_result'), ('item_three', 'item_three_result'), ('item_four', 'item_four_result'), ('item_five', 'item_five_result'), ('item_six', 'item_six_result')]
```

`\s*` matches zero or more space characters and `\S+` matches one or more non-space characters. `\G` assert position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/30)

Comment: i doubt about the spaces before each line in your input. Is there really any spaces before each line of text?

Comment: if there isn't any spaces then you could use this regex http://regex101.com/r/uK2aV8/2 which uses multiline flag. You don't need to go for verbose flag.

Comment: `There can be one item after a sentinel, or many` could you provide an example which replicate this?

Comment: it couldn't be possible through `re` module, but it could be possible through `regex` module. Did you wanna solution through regex module ?

Comment: @JohnSchmitt How about this http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/30 ? See my updated answer.

Comment: Amazing, yes that matched what I expected.  I do not understand \G though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66102/discussion-between-john-schmitt-and-avinash-raj).